# The page isn't redirecting properly when the permalink straucture for a page is customized in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When i edit**  permalink structure of a page in edit page link, it throws 
"The page isn't redirecting properly" when check in front end.

**changed parent page name in the link. Other pages are working fine even when the parent page name is changed

But when i preview the page the page is displayed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Login to WP-Admin > Go to Plugins > Locate Redirection plugin > Click the Groups link > Modified Posts > Check if your pages with redirection issues are there > Select and Edit to check or just delete them.